# Having trouble getting past NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I'm a newbie in programming, especially in c#. I have written some code but I keep getting an error when running it and I can't move on until I get that fixed.

The error in question is a NullReferenceException. It also tells me "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

It seems like a pretty clear error message indicating that an object hasn't been instantiated yet. However I thought I had done that. I hope someone can explain to me what I'm doing wrong. Here's my code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace EvenHelemaalOvernieuw
{
    class Globals
    {
        public static int size = 50;
        public static int factor = 3;
        public static int puzzleNumber = 1;
        public static Square[,] allSquares = new Square[Globals.factor * Globals.factor, Globals.factor * Globals.factor];
        public static String path = @"" + factor.ToString() + "\\" + puzzleNumber.ToString() + ".txt";
        public static int[,][,] values = new int[factor, factor][,];

        public Globals() { }

        public void setSize(int s)
        {
            size = s;
            if (size > 100)
            {
                size = 100;
            }
            if (size < 20)
            {
                size = 20;
            }
        }

        public void setFactor(int f)
        {
            factor = f;
            if (factor > 5)
            {
                factor = 5;
            }
            if (factor < 2)
            {
                factor = 2;
            }
        }

        public Square getSquare(int x, int y)
        {
            return allSquares[x, y];
        }

        public static void readPuzzle()
        {
            List<int> conversion = new List<int>();
            int count = 0;
            using (StreamReader codeString = new StreamReader(path))
            {
                String line = codeString.ReadToEnd();
                Array characters = line.ToCharArray();
                foreach (char a in characters)
                {
                    if (a.ToString() != ",")
                    {
                        conversion.Add(Convert.ToInt32(a));
                    }
                }
                for (int panelX = 0; panelX < factor; panelX++)
                {
                    for (int panelY = 0; panelY < factor; panelY++)
                    {
                        for (int squareX = 0; squareX < factor; squareX++)
                        {
                            for (int squareY = 0; squareY < factor; squareY++)
                            {
                                values[panelX, panelY][squareX, squareY] = conversion[count];
                                count++;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
   }
}
```

The line that is indicated by the error message is near the bottom and reads `values[panelX, panelY][squareX, squareY] = conversion[count];`.

Comment: Your sample missing code that initializes `values[panelX, panelY]` - please post that portion too.

Comment: You have understood the message and analyzed the problem a bit. It is so refreshing to see a question where this was done. +10

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is the following line

```
public static int[,][,] values = new int[factor, factor][,];
```

This is an array of arrays but this code only creates the outer array.  The inner array is uninitialized and will be `null`.  Hence when the following code runs it will throw a `NullReferenceException` trying to access the inner array

```
values[panelX, panelY][squareX, squareY] = conversion[count];
```

To fix this just initialize the array elements right before the 3rd nested loop

```
values[panelX, panelY] = new int[factor, factor];
for (int squareX = 0; squareX < factor; squareX++)
```

Comment: This did the trick! Thanks for your help. My code is not doing what I expected it to, but at least now I can see what's going on and try to get that fixed.